# Extract features from Alphapose keypoints output

Tags: pose-estimation

I am currently trying to use Alphapose keypoints output.
I have a few questions.

1. I am wondering how can I use these output to **extract the features like cadence, stride length and more.**
2. I am wondering **how many frames** are generated each minute. My below json actually contained more than hundreds of jpegs. below is just a sample.

-> Here is the output examples:

```
[{'image_id': '3.jpg',
  'category_id': 1,
  'keypoints': [3084.453125,
   766.064453125,
   0.27073606848716736,
   3109.76806640625,
   808.2561645507812,
   0.21385984122753143,
   3084.453125,
   766.064453125,
   0.24748951196670532,
   3109.76806640625,
   875.7628173828125,
   0.3147721290588379,
   3084.453125,
   715.4345092773438,
   0.20229308307170868,
   3067.576416015625,
   1019.2144775390625,
   0.4297007918357849,
   3050.69970703125,
   732.3111572265625,
   0.32160425186157227,
   2881.93310546875,
   968.58447265625,
   0.32375261187553406,
   2848.1796875,
   681.68115234375,
   0.3226509690284729,
   2730.043212890625,
   867.324462890625,
   0.5148664116859436,
   2730.043212890625,
   782.941162109375,
   0.33549684286117554,
   2763.79638671875,
   884.201171875,
   0.29956817626953125,
   2831.30322265625,
   766.064453125,
   0.22447820007801056,
   2308.12646484375,
   884.201171875,
   0.2733159065246582,
   2325.003173828125,
   901.0778198242188,
   0.2143297791481018,
   1717.4429931640625,
   917.9544677734375,
   0.3410451412200928,
   1683.689697265625,
   934.8311767578125,
   0.3064221441745758],
  'score': 1.1431528329849243,
  'box': [1685.37744140625,
   665.083251953125,
   1296.1279296875,
   421.359130859375],
  'idx': [0.0]},
 {'image_id': '6.jpg',
  'category_id': 1,
  'keypoints': [2716.578125,
   708.694580078125,
   0.20404888689517975,
   2760.772705078125,
   693.9630126953125,
   0.24653863906860352,
   2731.3095703125,
   679.2314453125,
   0.24123729765415192,
   3003.84375,
   878.107666015625,
   0.1836661398410797,
   2981.746337890625,
   679.2314453125,
   0.16582731902599335,
   3003.84375,
   966.4970703125,
   0.1983313262462616,
   2967.014892578125,
   708.694580078125,
   0.313667356967926,
   3003.84375,
   1025.42333984375,
   0.3715871572494507,
   2760.772705078125,
   826.5471801757812,
   0.2802092432975769,
   2760.772705078125,
   856.0103149414062,
   0.32904109358787537,
   2760.772705078125,
   826.5471801757812,
   0.27431410551071167,
   2701.846435546875,
   929.6681518554688,
   0.16013894975185394,
   2628.188720703125,
   885.4734497070312,
   0.18557937443256378,
   2318.82568359375,
   914.9365844726562,
   0.33809077739715576,
   2333.55712890625,
   900.2050170898438,
   0.24967674911022186,
   1714.8311767578125,
   929.6681518554688,
   0.40348780155181885,
   1744.2943115234375,
   914.9365844726562,
   0.271779328584671],
  'score': 0.8994148969650269,
  'box': [1760.4990234375, 702.509521484375, 1131.384765625, 410.12255859375],
  'idx': [0.0]}]
```

Here is the reference I used.
https://github.com/MVIG-SJTU/AlphaPose

Comment: any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: is there anyone having any suggestions?